# Change Entity Value In hook_feeds_presave()

Tags: feeds

I am trying to modify data coming from a feed before it saved to a node by using hook_feeds_presave().

I have code that looks like this:

```
my_module_feeds_presave(FeedsSource $source, $entity, $item) {
     $email =  $item['email address'];
    //Remove "NOT GIVEN" from the email column to stop errors
    if($email == "NOT GIVEN"){
        $entity->field_email['und'][0]['value'] = '';
    } 
}
```

I would think that when the node is saved that value in the email filed would be blank. However, it is still saving the value of *NOT GIVEN.*

If anyone can please point me in the right direction with this I would appreciate it.

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: did you try the patch in this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds/issues/1703074) ?

Comment: Thank you for the issue but this patch is for sure in my version as I am getting the correct value from the $issue variable.

Answer (score 1):

Can you mention your Drupal version?

- For Drupal 7, your code looks good enough at a first glance.
- If it's Drupal 8, all you need is `$entity->field_email = ''`.

If that doesn't work, leave a comment and I'll take a detailed look.

Comment: It is Drupal 7 and it does not work. The node API is still seeing NOT GIVEN.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the email field from the [Email Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/email) module, then the column you need to save the value under is '**email**', not 'value'.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_feeds_presave().
 */
function my_module_feeds_presave(FeedsSource $source, $entity, $item) {
  if ($source->importer->id != 'my_importer') {
    // No modification needed for this importer.
    return;
  }

  $email = $item['email address'];
  // Remove "NOT GIVEN" from the email column to stop errors.
  if ($email == "NOT GIVEN"){
    $entity->field_email['und'][0]['email'] = '';
  } 
}
```

Note that you can alternatively also use the hook `hook_feeds_after_parse()` to modify the parsed data:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_feeds_after_parse().
 */
function my_module_feeds_after_parse(FeedsSource $source, FeedsParserResult $result) {
  if ($source->importer->id != 'my_importer') {
    // No modification needed for this importer.
    return;
  }

  // Remove mail addresses that contain 'NOT GIVEN'.
  foreach ($result->items as &$item) {
    if (isset($item['email address']) && $item['email address'] == 'NOT GIVEN') {
      $item['email address'] = '';
    }
  }
}
```

Note that in the code examples above I added code to restrict modification to a particular importer. This is recommended if you are using multiple importers and the modification should only be applied to a single importer.